# How to conditionally set a value in schema

Tags: mongoose, schema

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: Number
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    max: function () { return /* insert code */ },
    required: function () { return this.id === 5 }
  }
})
```

It works for required, but how can I conditionally set the max value for amount to 100?

Comment: MAybe you need `max` in [number validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#number-validators) ?

Comment: What condition do you want? There is no need for a condition right if you know max value is 100.

Comment: Was just an example. Let's say I want it to be 100 if the id is 5, or 1000 if the id is something else